# Is EM radiation flux an extensive or intensive property?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation

Is electromagnetic radiation flux (measured in watts per square metre) an extensive or intensive property? Can the fluxes from two sources be somehow combined at a target and what are the rules?

Comment: From my understanding, "intensive" and "extensive" are used to describe properties of matter. Electromagnetic radiation isn't matter.

Comment: If there were two Suns in the sky, the average solar flux at the Earth would double: twice as many watts per square meter.

Comment: Smith, I believe your wrong, check my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in most cases that you would come across the radiation flux from two sources (e.g. two light bulbs, two stars, two car headlights) can just be added together to get the total radiation flux.

That is because most sources of light are sources of incoherent radiation. The light arises from multiple microscopic sources at multiple locations that have no fixed phase relationship, even on extremely short timescales.

The *exception* would be where you try to add together two sources of light that are coherent and have a fixed phase relationship - for example two laser beams that originate from the same parent beam. In such cases you need to add the amplitudes of the component electric and magnetic fields together before calculating the resultant Poynting vector and flux.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/61323/43351

Details:

For the case of two *coherent* sources with a fixed phase relationship between their electromagnetic fields (e.g., a pair of lasers with identical frequencies, or one laser and a beam splitter), it is straightforward to show that the summed Poynting vector
$$\vec{S} = \vec{E_1} \times \vec{H_1}  + \vec{E_2} \times \vec{H_2} + \vec{E_1} \times \vec{H_2} + \vec{E_2} \times \vec{H_1}$$
$$\vec{S} = \vec{S_1} + \vec{S_2} + \vec{E_1} \times \vec{H_2} + \vec{E_2} \times \vec{H_1}\ .$$
If there is a fixed phase relationship between wave 1 and wave 2, then the time-average (which is what is measured by any "flux detector") of the "crossed terms" is not necessarily zero and could be positive or negative. This is just constructive or destructive interference.

If there is no fixed phase relationship between the two sources, which is the case for every-day light sources or light coming from different points on a macroscopic source of radiation, then the crossed terms will have the form (assuming the waves are travelling along the z-axis in vacuum)
$$\vec{E_1} \times \vec{H_2} + \vec{E_2} \times \vec{H_1} = \frac{2E_1 E_2}{\mu_0 c} \sin(\omega t)\sin(\omega t + \phi)\ \hat{z}, $$
where $\phi$ is a random, time-varying phase difference. The time-average of this is zero, so
$$ \langle S \rangle = \langle S_1 \rangle + \langle S_2 \rangle$$
and the flux measured is the summed flux from the two sources.

Comment: Can you explain why incoherence means that $$\vec{E}_{1}× \vec{B}_{2} + \vec{E}_{2} × \vec{B}_{1} =0$$  Which is the conditions for $$\vec{S}_{1+2} = \vec{S}_{1} + \vec{S}_{2}$$

Comment: @jensenpaull  Why would its time-average be non-zero if there is no fixed phase relationship between $E_1$ and $E_2$ ? Note that the relevant relationship here is that $<S_{1+2}> = <S_1> + <S_2>$.

Answer (score -1):

They CANNOT be added. As consider 2 sources , producing 2 "independant" E and B fields.

$\vec{S_{1}} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{E_{1}}×\vec{B_{1}}$

$\vec{S_{2}} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{E_{2}}×\vec{B_{2}}$,

$\vec{S_{1}} + \vec{S_{2}}$

Does not equal:

$\vec{S}_{1+2}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\vec{E_{1}}+\vec{E_{2}})×(\vec{B_{1}}+\vec{B_{2}})$

There are cross terms when considering the total Poynting vector as a result of 2 different E and B fields, that are not present if we just "add" the poynting vector of them up individually.

Doubling the E and B field, would NOT double the power.

Comment: I think there's some discussion of coherence and expectation required here.  If the sources are not coherent then the expected values of the cross terms would go to zero?

Comment: This is an extremely interesting answer that has huge implications in other areas. I would like to continue the discussion offline. I have just a couple of questions / observations; please contact me at cones.purgers-0p@icloud.com (a hide-my-email from Apple). Thanks, johnM

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Because it isn't the correct answer to the question asked. Radiation flux can be combined by simple addition and $S_{1+2} = S_1 + S_2$,  *except* in cases where you are trying to combine the light from two *coherent* light sources. G.Smith's comment that you disagreed with, is correct.

Comment: Jensen Paull's answer is correct. 
Not only that, from a simple (but not so crude) home experiment, it appears that if you have two sources and one target:
If Source A produces Ta at the target, Source B produces Tb at the target, then with both sources on, the target becomes Ta or Tb whichever is the greater. 
Adding fluxes together creates temperature which are much too high.
I'll be happy to post my two-page description somewhere is there is a need.

Comment: @JohnMurphy please publish the details and results of your home experiment that shows that two light bulbs are not twice as bright as one light bulb. It would be big news indeed for light bulb manufacturers.

Comment: @ProfRob will do late this week or early next week. Will put on DropBox or GDrive - but if there is a "usual" location for these type of files (2/4 page PDF) please let me know.

Comment: @jensenpaull and others. The file can be seen here 
https://cldup.com/nkUQa-UIhJ.pdf
The results are fairly conclusive, but it needs to be performed in a vacuum if only for completeness. The conclusion is that radiative flux has "intensive" properties and should not be "added" to other radiative flux streams. 
Further, given two sources, the temperature created at a target is the same as the highest created by either of the two individual sources. 
All comments, suggestions etc welcome - including offers to run something similar in a vacuum with good equipment.

Comment: @ProfRob. I'm never quite sure how this works - but see the comment above. The file can be seen at https://cldup.com/nkUQa-UIhJ.pdf Would be interested to know what you think.

Comment: Slight mistake in file; please use this one https://cloudup.com/cljKgkNVH8o

Comment: @jensenpaull You may want to look at this "paper". Would be interested in your comments. https://cloudup.com/cljKgkNVH8o