# What does it imply when we say that the waves are perfectly correlated?

Tags: optics, waves, quantum-optics, coherence

I am having a hard time understanding difference between correlation and coherence. I got a nice answer for coherence here- [Are two waves being in phase is the same as saying that the two waves are coherent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56588/are-two-waves-being-in-phase-is-the-same-as-saying-that-the-two-waves-are-cohere)
I am taking a course named "coherence and quantum entanglement" and it seems like both the terms are being used equivalently.

Comment: have you checked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation). Also, have you asked your lecturer to explain?

Comment: I might be wrong as quantum optics is not exactly my field but: 2 correlated (in entanglement) photons will have to be coherent, i. e. their relative phase is fixed, because the process for their generation is coherent and preserves phase. However I can have photons which are coherent (same sort of fixed phase relationship) but which are not correlated. Take laser amplification for example. In other words correlation (in entanglement) implies coherence, but the opposite might not be true.

Comment: *some sort of fixed